# Zend Framework 2 - Setting serviceLocator in HydratorPluginManager not working

Tags: php, zend-framework2, service-locator

I am using a `HydratorPluginManager` (Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\HydratorPluginManager) to manage my hydrators in one single spot and to let the manager take care of validation of my hydrators (meaning checking if my hydrators properly implement the `HydratorInterface`).

I have some hydrators that I created using factories like this:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'My\Hydrators\SomeHydrator' => 'My\Hydrators\SomeHydratorFactory'
    )
)
```

After registering the factories in my config file these hydrators are without any problem available in my `ServiceManager` using `$serviceManager->get($name)`. Now I would like to connect my `ServiceManager` to my `HydratorManager` so that if I ask for a certain hydrator using:

```
$hydratorPluginManager->get($name)
```

where `$name` is the alias used for registering. So in this example it would be:

```
$hydratorPluginManager->get('My\Hydrators\SomeHydrator');
```

My idea was that if I connect my `ServiceManager` like this:

```
$hydratorPluginManager->setServiceLocator($serviceManager)
```

It should work. But it doesn't and I am very confused why this is not working...

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just put the hydrators in the plugin manager directly. The hydrator plugin manager is configured in the same way it is for the service manager (invokables, factories, etc), only the config key is different, `hydrators` instead of `service_manager`

You just need to move your factories from `service_manager` to `hydrators` ...

```
'hydrators' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'My\Hydrators\SomeHydrator' => 'My\Hydrators\SomeHydratorFactory'
    )
),
```